# this type of clause was previously parsed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query working fine.

```
  SELECT d.customer_id,
          d.fname,
          d.lname,
          m.lastDate,
     (SELECT COUNT(order_id)
      FROM `orders`
      WHERE `customer_id`=d.customer_id
      ) AS 'total_orders',
          d.isActive
   FROM customers d
   JOIN `orders` m ON m.order_id=
     (SELECT order_id
      FROM `orders`
      WHERE customer_id=d.customer_id
      ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 1
      )
   WHERE d.user_id=382
     AND d.customer_id NOT IN
       (SELECT `customer_id`
        FROM `orders`
        WHERE `balance`>0
          AND `isActive`=1
        )
```

The above query works fine but when add and union query to also includes customer that have not placed any orders it does work.

```
   SELECT d.customer_id,
          d.fname,
          d.lname,
          m.lastDate,
     (SELECT COUNT(order_id)
      FROM `orders`
      WHERE `customer_id`=d.customer_id
      ) AS 'total_orders',
          d.isActive
   FROM customers d
   JOIN `orders` m ON m.order_id=
     (SELECT order_id
      FROM `orders`
      WHERE customer_id=d.customer_id
      ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 1
      )
   WHERE d.user_id=382
     AND d.customer_id NOT IN
       (SELECT `customer_id`
        FROM `orders`
        WHERE `balance`>0
          AND `isActive`=1
        )

UNION 

#customer WITH NO ORDERS
  SELECT `customer_id`,`fname`,`lname`,`state`,`city`,`isActive`
   FROM `customers`
   WHERE `user_id`=382
     AND `isActive` >-1
     AND `customer_id` NOT IN
       (SELECT `customer_id`
        FROM `orders`
        )
```

It display this error in my phpmyadmin

This type of clause was previously parsed (near select)

Comment: Can you add the `UNION` query as well

Comment: done, see my edit. i was having a hard time formatting the codes.

Comment: Your second query in `UNION` doesn't have any `total_orders` column. Is that intentional? This is the reason you cannot union these two.

Comment: That was actually intentional because my second query doesn't have those 2 columns since I'm selecting customer with no order history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, I don't believe you want to use `union` -- you want to use an `outer join` instead. Here's a slightly simplified version of your query utilizing `joins` instead of all those `correlated subqueries`.

```
SELECT  d.customer_id, d.fname, d.lname, d.isactive,
        o.lastdate, 
        Count(o2.order_id) AS 'total_orders'
 FROM   customers d 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(order_id) order_id, customer_id
              FROM   orders 
              GROUP BY customer_id) m on d.customer_id = m.customer_id
        LEFT JOIN orders o on m.order_id = o.order_id
        LEFT JOIN orders o2 on d.customer_id = o2.customer_id 
                           AND o2.balance > 0 AND o2.isactive = 1
 WHERE  d.user_id = 382 
        AND o2.customer_id IS NULL
 GROUP BY d.customer_id
```

---

BTW -- Reviewing your edits, when using `union` statements, you must have the same number of columns with the same types in each `select` list.  The `state` and `city` fields in the second query probably don't have the same data type as the `lastDate` and `count` fields from the first.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i think we are almost there.This is the result at the moment http://s13.postimg.org/clkteyliv/Untitled.png. total_orders is not displaying 0 for all customer. also can you help me alter the query to includes customer with d.isAactive 0 and exclude d.isActive -1 because these are deleted customers

Comment: I know i did not address this in my op thread but customer id 271 shouldn't be there because is a customer that was deleted.