# MySql query to select total orders for customers

Tags: mysql, sql

There title does not quite describe well what i need from the query.

@sgeddes helped me come up with the following query but the query needs some alteration to accomplish my needs. I also modified the query slightly to not Select deleted customers but i couldn't change much due to the way this query is written is out my SQL knowledge.

```
SELECT  d.customer_id,d.fname,d.lname,d.isactive,
        o.lastdate, 
        Count(o2.order_id) AS 'total_orders'
 FROM   customers d
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(order_id) order_id, customer_id
              FROM   orders 
              GROUP BY customer_id) m on d.customer_id = m.customer_id
        LEFT JOIN orders o on m.order_id = o.order_id
        LEFT JOIN orders o2 on d.customer_id = o2.customer_id 
                           AND o2.balance > 0 AND o2.isActive > -1
 WHERE  d.user_id =945766  AND d.isActive > -1 
        AND o2.customer_id IS NULL
GROUP BY d.customer_id
```

I need the three following requirements.

1. count orders for customer with isActive > -1 (-1 = deleted)
2. Customers not in orders table (customer with no orders).
3. Customers with isActive = 0 and their corresponding order count

so briefly all I need is customer with isActive = 0 and to get an actual # for total_orders column.

In my attempt to better help you understand my requirement I created a SqlFiddle.

[Please see my SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44998/1)

Comment: may be this query was designed for some other purpose and to edit it can be more complex even you need a simply query...so just let us know what is your requirement.

Comment: So you want 3 separate queries for 3 separate results?

Comment: @strawberry. i was using 3 separate queries merged by UNION and as suggested by sgeddes in my previous thread i started using his version of the query instead.

Comment: But what's wrong with 3 separate queries?

Comment: @ZafarMalik I believe so since in my previous thread about this requirement i was not clear at first of all my requirements. Please see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36051226/this-type-of-clause-was-previously-parsed/36051428#36051428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is what you mentioned in your 3 points then you can use below queries-

**If you want separate query then use below-**

```
SELECT d.customer_id, d.fname, COUNT(o.order_id) AS Total_Orders
FROM customer d 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON d.customer_id=o.customer_id 
WHERE d.isActive > -1
GROUP BY d.customer_id;

SELECT DISTINCT d.customer_id, d.fname 
FROM customer d 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON d.customer_id=o.customer_id 
WHERE o.customer_id IS NULL;

SELECT d.customer_id, d.fname, COUNT(o.order_id) AS Total_Orders
FROM customer d 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON d.customer_id=o.customer_id 
WHERE d.isActive = 0 
GROUP BY d.customer_id;
```

**If you want to merge them by union then use below-**

```
SELECT 'isactive>-1' AS 'status', d.customer_id, d.fname, COUNT(o.order_id) AS Total_Orders
FROM customer d 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON d.customer_id=o.customer_id 
WHERE d.isActive > -1
GROUP BY d.customer_id 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'Customer without Order' AS 'status', d.customer_id, d.fname, COUNT(o.order_id) AS Total_Orders 
FROM customer d 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON d.customer_id=o.customer_id 
WHERE o.customer_id IS NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'isactive=0' AS 'status', d.customer_id, d.fname, COUNT(o.order_id) AS Total_Orders
FROM customer d 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON d.customer_id=o.customer_id 
WHERE d.isActive = 0 
GROUP BY d.customer_id;
```

Note: Your main query is trying fetch latest order which can be for any other purpose, so if you provide your exact requirement if different from it then someone can help you.

Comment: sorry at the time of merge I forgot to remove mysql terminator ";" now I have removed please check now.

Comment: i will accept your answer because your query return my expected result however the first subquery is counting o.isActive=-1(deleted orders) as well so when i add 'AND o.isActive > -1' the results from the second sub query (customers with no orders) are all gone. idk why.

Comment: Actually in your main query you used customer and order both active status, I checked status only for customer..so you can add condition as per your need either only cutomer isactive or order or both.

Comment: yeah so i added a condition for o.isActive as well. Now the whole where clause look like this "WHERE d.isActive > -1 and o.isActive > -1".  my question is that after i added the condition the customer with no orders(second query) are all gone. i mean they not being returned from the query. i dont know why.

Comment: ok i fixed it. instead of UNION ALL i started using just UNION and it works fine now. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: If you use union all the query will show duplicate results also but if you use just union and it will provide you distinct records from all sub queries.....regarding in 2nd sub-query, there should not be any condition in where clause on order table same i think you have fixed.